# Is there a way I can use the AEM SPA editor on an Angular Application which is developed using Redux pattern?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, redux, aem, single-page-application

I was just trying to integrate the AEM SPA editor to my existing angular application which is developed mostly by following the Redux pattern. So all the presentational components, I was aiming to expose as an AEM component are dumb. They will get its data through `@Input()` and the user interactions are managed by the EventEmitters with an `@Output()` directive. Some of the input values are dynamic which are supplied by the parent component to the dumb components by reading the Redux state store.

[image: High level structure of my Page]

Since the AEM is only responsible for the static content, I am not sure how to achieve the dynamic behavior of the dumb components. Some of the things that I have tried (Added below) so far are in fact beats the whole purpose of the Redux Pattern.

- Injected the state store into the dumb components and read the data directly from it instead of relying on the supplied data through the `@Input()` directive. In this case, I will use mock data to support the authoring experience.

I am not able to turn my head around this problem. My questions are:

1. Is this even possible in AEM?
2. Is my understanding of the AEM is completely wrong?
3. Is the AEM not matured yet to support SPAs developed using the Redux pattern?
4. Should I create a single component in AEM which maps to the Parent component in Angular?

Thanks in Advance. Any help will be much appreciated.